# Express static file middleware isnt etting css file as public

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I'm trying to set my css files as public so that my server can recognize them, i'm using  the correct funtion and i am putting my css file in the right folder (public), i have linked the file in my ejs files with the right directory, but for some reason my server still doesn't find the file. I think its not recognizing the file because the direcotry im putting in isn't right.

Here is my html code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title><%= title %></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/15th_Lesson/public/styles.css" />
```

(the code is in a partial since all my html files have the same head secition and this paart is the one with the link so i put only it in here)

Here is my js code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.listen(3000);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

(in `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` i tired using just `app.use(express.static('public'));` but it still didn't work)

Here is my directory:[image]

Here are all of the files inside the 15th_lesson file(where my project is):

[image]

And here is what my network tab in the borwser looks like: [image]

Here is my css code (very basic): `body{background-color: black;}`

I apologize if anything is unclear, i will gladly clear up any confusion in the comments.

Comment: The link `/15th_Lesson/public/styles.css` should be relative to the public directory so more like this `/styles.css` You can test it simply by typing this url in your browser `localhost:3000/styles.css`

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. This works im just cofused as to why it can recognize the css file even though its inside 2 different folders. If you have the time and patience to answer, an aswer would be highly appreciated. I also apologize for being bothersome and not trying this when i was working on it.

Comment: I can explain,  express.static will look for your file recursivelly. app.use('/endpoint', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'yourDirectory'))); would return all files inside of the yourDirectory folder, and they will be visible via get request or just go to http://example.com/endpoint/yourDirectory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one in your .ejs file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
```